# Jquery code will not work in IE

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-9

I am baffled by this problem, which appears to have begun after I launched the IE 9 developer tool. I'm developing in Visual Studio 08 (because pages are part of an ASP.net ap) and all of a sudden simple Jquery selectors that work in all other browsers do not work in IE -- either in the VS internal browser (IE7) or in the freestanding IE 9. Visual Studio tells me that a Jquery plugin (either Scrollpane or Preload, depending on which is called first) is "undefined." I get no other errors.

I have removed the plugins and references to them. I also removed an overlay that blocks clicks during preloading. This makes no difference to IE.

This is the line of code that, no matter how explicit I make it, will not run in IE:

```
$('#pictureholder > div.display > img[src|="' +  image + '"]').parent('div.display').removeClass('noshow').addClass('nowshow').fadeIn('slow');
```

This runs in other browsers with or without the explicit parent selectors.

Comment: did you try getting rid of your direct descendant selectors?

Comment: what stores in image = ?

Comment: Lots of questions there. "What's `image`?" being the most pressing. Do you really have an element with the `id` "pictureholder" with an *immediate* child that's a `div` with class "display" that has an *immediate* child that's an `img` where `src` contains `image` (whatever that is)... Is the `div.display` really hidden. Have you broken that down into its component parts and walked through in a debugger to see which part isn't work. Etc.

Comment: When you say that it "will not run," what do you mean?  Meaning it has no visual impact or you get an error?  If there's no visual impact, check your CSS and JS inclusion order in your HTML header.  Make sure CSS comes first.

Comment: image is a variable for a clicked on photo with a name that matches save for the addition of thumb ($(this).attr("src").replace("Thumb", "")

Comment: I do indeed have an element with id pictureholder of which the div.display is a direct child. the img's src matches the string variable image. I've walked through all in a debugger and watched the classes change in chrome's tool.

Comment: When I say will not run I mean that nothing happens on the click event. The css works (the cursor appropriately changes over the thumb image) and the style sheets are on top of the javascript files.

Comment: clarifying. the click event fires just fine in all other browsers but ie

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with the attribute-selector of the `<img>`.

Sizzle uses in UAs that don't support querySelectorAll() elem[attr], what returns the translated path of the image-src. So the selector will not match.
This is a real bug I think, because it's not the behaviour as defined inside the CSS-specification.

You may use filter() instead:

```
$('#pictureholder > div.display > img')
 .filter(function(){return $(this).attr('src').match(new RegExp('^('+image+'|'+image+'-.*)$'));})
  .parent('div.display')//continue the chain here
```

Or change the behaviour of Sizzle. To do this, insert right after the embedded jquery.js the following instruction:

```
jQuery.find.selectors.attrHandle.src= function( elem ) 
{
  return elem.getAttribute( "src",2 );
}
```

(It will force Sizzle to work with the attribute as defined inside the document instead of the element's property)

Comment: I'm not using Sizzle, but thanks for helping me to understand what's happening. IE is not recognizing "src" : var h = $('img[src|="' +  image + '"]').attr('id');
alert(h);

Comment: sorry, continuing. I gave some of the images ids to test. IE alerts "undefined" whereas all other browsers return the id. I'm going to try searching for the image as a text node ... or enclose it in divs or spans... or something.

Comment: Well the solution was utterly simple: I simply used the image url for the alt as well as the src, changed references to src to alt and it all works the way I expected it to this morning. It makes me hope that Microsoft won't subject Skype to its meticulous development. Thanks to Dr. Molle who pointed out the improbable problem.

Comment: This is not a problem of IE or MS, the problem occurs in jQuery.